# Use Python for Measuring read/write speed while copying a file between PC and Android phone

Tags: python

I have a scenario as below
I copy a file 1 GB size from phone to PC. I want to measure the speed of phone
I copy a file 1GB size from PC to phone. I want to measure the speed of PC.
I want to use Python to make it. Do you know any module or anything support this.

I tried researching but no matching solution, especially by python.

Comment: As long as you don't need fine grained measurements of the transfer in progress, you can get the start and end times with `time.time()`. Assuming you are just issuing a command for the copy, you could use `subprocess.run()` after getting start time.

Comment: BTW `timeit.default_timer()` is much more reliable (has monotonic guarantee).